# Blue/Green deployment with dbt on Databricks suggestions

Tags: databricks, dbt

When running dbt I'm executing it in different steps, basically bronze -> silver -> gold in different commands. This gives us the oppertunity that when one of the layers fails, it doesnt break the downstream models (for refreshing against PBI).

Now I'm looking into making the pipelines more simple and want to just run a full `dbt build` instead of partially. The idea is to use a blue/green deployment structure for that. Like we have a live catalog and a stage catalog. You release to stage, then switch it over to live. As far as I'm aware of Databricks doesn't have nice functionality for that.

Snowflake has the `ALTER DATABASE {db} SWAP WITH {other_db}`.

I've been testing with cloning or creating views of all the tables/views to a 'production' catalog, however this adds more complexities i think.

Does anyone have a nice suggestion? I'm okay with a discussion.